# NSFileManager Create Directory Failed with Error Code 513

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

There is a horrible bug which is only occurring intermittently. I'm trying to save data into a sub-folder in 'Application Support' folder. Before saving I will create that sub-folder if not exists

```
NSString *cachePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
NSString *packagePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ResourcePackage"];

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL isDirectory = NO;
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:packagePath isDirectory:&isDirectory] || !isDirectory)
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:packagePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```

Everything goes fine but except for only one device on which will get error with code 513

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "您没有将文件“ResourcePackage”存储到文件夹“Application Support”中的权限。" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4FF643C4-D568-417F-9A88-5E9FF2326972/Library/Application Support/ResourcePackage, NSUnderlyingError=0x17425e6f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}
```

What have I missed or am I doing wrong while writing to this directory?

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you try to save on DocumentDirectory